# CakePHP - Create an Offline/Online feature for a site

Tags: cakephp

======================================== **EDIT** ====================================

Per charles suggestion, I accomplished the Offline/Online feature using the following code, based on Charles code:

```
<?php

      Class AppController extends Controller{

          // prevents unauthorized access
          public $components = array('Auth');

          // the name of the model storing site_offline boolean
          public $uses = array('Configuration');

          // callback invoked before every controller action
          public function beforeFilter() {

              // returns your site_offline status assuming 0 is offline
              if ($this->Configuration->get_site_status() == 1) {
                   $this->Auth->allow('*');
              }else {
                   if(($this->Configuration->get_site_status() == 0) and (!$this->Auth->user() == null)){
                       // I set it up like this for now to allow access to any authenticated user, 
                       //but later will change it to only allow admins access thru a login form
                       $this->Auth->allow('*');
                   }else{ 
                       //If site is offline and user is not authenticated, sent them to 
                       // the a screen using the OFFLINE layout and provide a screen for login.
                       $this->layout = 'offline';  
                       $this->setFlash('Maintenance Mode. Check back shortly.');
                       $this->Auth->deny('*');
                   }
              }

          }

       }
 ?>
```

Then I used jQuery to hide my login form. An admin clicks on the message to show the login form. This is an attempt to prevent any login tryouts.

============================ END EDIT ==========================================

I would like to know what is the best way to create a "site offline/online" feature in CakePHP. Basically, I would like to allow an administrator to turn off access to the site to everyone registered or not. The offline page should have a login access thru which only admins can login.

The idea I have is to create some kind of dashboard controller, where as soon as the administrator is logged in he/she will be redirected to this dashboard from where he can access the other controller actions (admin_edit, etc). This dashboard and all admin actions (admin_delete, etc) should use the admin layout.

Is this a good approach? For the offline/online feature should I create a settings table with a site_offline field that can be turned on or off? Where in app_controller and what code should I use to check for it before allowing or not access to the site?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Comment: You can also look into [moving-a-cakephp-app](http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/09/29/moving-a-cakephp-app) and how you can leverage a Maintenance shell to activate/deactivate maintenance mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were going to save site_offline boolean value in a database table you should be able to easily do this with a callback in AppController and the Auth component.

```
<?php

AppController extends Object {

    // prevents unauthorized access
    public $components = array('Auth');

    // the name of the model storing site_offline boolean
    public $uses = array('NameOfModel');

    // callback invoked before every controller action
    public function beforeFilter() {

        // returns your site_offline status assuming 0 is offline
        if ($this->NameOfModel->get_status() === 0) {
             $this->Auth->deny('*');
        } else {
             $this->Auth->allow('*');
        }

    }

}
```

I've always liked the idea of the DashboardsController for admin functions.  That's actually the exact name of the class I use and the same general idea.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This looks pretty legit. I will try that and post back.

Comment: Charles, I've updated my original question with the solution based on your help. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

first add a config in the **core.config**

```
/*
 * This is the site maintenance 
 *   The built in defaults are:
 *
 * - '1' - Site works
 * - '0' - site down for maintenance.
 */

Configure::write('Site.status', 1);
```

in the **AppController** you'll check it in the **beforeRender** function

```
if (Configure::read('Site.status') == 0) {
            $this->layout = 'maintenance';
            $this->set('title_for_layout', __('Site_down_for_maintenance_title'));
        } else {
// do something
}
```

i'm here load a separate  layout form the maintenance to let me add whatever layout i want

Comment: I took care of this awhile ago but using a Database and not the core.php file. By using the DB I can easily switch site on and off in the administration section

Comment: You'd probably want `beforeFilter` rather than `beforeRender`, since the latter is called _after_ an action and could read/write from the database (which presumably you don't want in maintenance mode).